# How to build Botan amalgamation files botan_all.cpp and .h on windows

Tags: c++, windows, botan

As the title already suggested I try to make the botan_all files to integrate botan directly into my project. I installed python on my Windows and run the following command in the console:

```
C:\Temp\Botan-1.11.16>configure.py --cc=msvc --single-amalgamation-file
```

which leads to following output:

> INFO: Platform: OS="Windows" machine="AMD64" proc="Intel64 Family 6
>   Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel"    INFO: Guessing target OS is
>   windows (use --os to set)    INFO: Guessing target processor is a
>   x86_64/x86_64 (use --cpu to set)    INFO: Target is
>   msvc-windows-x86_64-x86_64    INFO: Skipping, by request only - cvc
>   INFO: Skipping, dependency failure - sessions_sqlite3 sha1_x86_64
>   INFO: Skipping, incompatible CPU - md4_x86_32 md5_x86_32
>   mp_x86_32_msvc serpe nt_x86_32 sha1_x86_32    INFO: Skipping,
>   incompatible OS - asm_x86_32 asm_x86_64 beos_stats dev_random  egd
>   fd_unix locking_allocator proc_walk unix_procs    INFO: Skipping,
>   incompatible compiler - mp_x86_32 mp_x86_64 rdrand simd_altiv ec
>   INFO: Skipping, loaded only if needed by dependency - dyn_load
>   simd_scalar    INFO: Skipping, requires external dependency - boost
>   bzip2 lzma openssl sqlit e3 zlib    INFO: Using MP module mp_generic
>   INFO: Using SIMD module simd_sse2    INFO: Loading modules adler32
>   aead aes aes_ni aes_ssse3 alloc aont asn1 auto_ rng base base64 bcrypt
>   benchmark bigint block blowfish camellia cascade cast cbc  cbc_mac ccm
>   cfb chacha chacha20poly1305 clmul cmac codec_filt comb4p compressio n
>   crc24 crc32 credentials cryptoapi_rng cryptobox ctr curve25519
>   datastor des dh  dl_algo dl_group dlies dsa eax ec_gfp ec_group ecb
>   ecc_key ecdh ecdsa elgamal e me_oaep eme_pkcs1 eme_raw emsa1 emsa1_bsi
>   emsa_pkcs1 emsa_pssr emsa_raw emsa_x93 1 entropy ffi filters fpe_fe1
>   gcm gost_28147 gost_3410 gost_3411 has160 hash has h_id hex hkdf hmac
>   hmac_drbg hmac_rng hres_timer http_util idea idea_sse2 if_alg o kasumi
>   kdf kdf1 kdf2 keccak keypair lion mac mars mce mceies md2 md4 md5
>   mdx_h ash mgf1 misty1 mode_pad modes mp mp_generic noekeon
>   noekeon_simd nr numbertheor y ocb ofb oid_lookup openpgp par_hash
>   passhash9 pbes2 pbkdf pbkdf1 pbkdf2 pem pk
>   _pad poly1305 prf_tls prf_x942 pubkey rc2 rc4 rc5 rc6 rfc3394 rfc6979 rmd128 rmd 160 rng rsa rw safer salsa20 seed serpent serpent_simd
>   sessions_sql sha1 sha1_ss e2 sha2_32 sha2_64 simd simd_sse2 siphash
>   siv skein srp6 stream system_rng tea t hreefish threefish_avx2 tiger
>   tls tss twofish utils whirlpool win32_stats x509 x 919_mac x931_rng
>   xtea xtea_simd xts    INFO: Assuming CPU is little endian    INFO:
>   Assuming unaligned memory access works    INFO: Using hardlink to link
>   files into build dir (use --link-method to chang e)    INFO: Botan
>   1.11.16 (released dated 20150330) build setup is complete

After that I do not know what to do next. I cannot find the botan_all files anywhere.

Comment: Did you read all of the instructions for Windows? The next step would be `nmake`.

Comment: Yes. But that is not the problem. I found out that the parameter is not working as described. --single-amalgamation-file has no effect at all. I answer my question myself a little later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `--gen-amalgamation` flag.  Your command should look like:

```
python configure.py --cc=msvc --gen-amalgamation --single-amalgamation-file
```

For newer versions you have to use `--amalgamation` instead of `--gen-amalgamation`.